# parse HTML including span tags whit Jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

[HERE is code from site ...span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t4eA.jpg)

```
Document b=Jsoup.connect("https://www.flashscore.ro/meci/CpNbKtrI/#sumar-meci").timeout(6000).get();
    String test2 = b.select("div.event_detail_current_result").text();
    System.out.println("This : " + test2);
```

and I need an idea how can i parse the website and print score

Comment: I'm tempted to share the "HTML cannot be parsed with a regex" posting but that probably really doesn't apply. But you are using JSoup, no? What have you tried using that API? Edit the question and show some code (as a [mcve]) that reproduces the problem you are having and a description of the problem or errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

`event_detail_current_result` is an `id` of element, not class name.
You should use:

```
String test2 = b.select("div#event_detail_current_result").text();
```

Read:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax for further explanation.